# Coercing Json Serializer into producing a particular datetime format (yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.msmsmsZ)

Tags: c#, json, datetime, jsonserializer

```
MyClass theSession = new MyClass() {
    accountId = 12345,
    timeStamp = DateTime.Now,
    userType = "theUserType"
};

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer Json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
Response.Write(Json.Serialize(theSession));
```

Produces:

```
{"accountId":12345,"timeStamp":"\/Date(1268420981135)\/","userType":"theUserType"}
```

How can I present the date as:

```
"timestamp":"2010-02-15T23:53:35.963Z"
```

?

Comment: You could always have your JS interpret it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you implement a JavaScriptConverter you would have to wrap the string in an object. Fortunately there's a hack around it described here:

http://blog.calyptus.eu/seb/2011/12/custom-datetime-json-serialization/

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a [`JavaScriptConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx) class and register it using the [`RegisterConverters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.registerconverters.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you (and everybody else with this problem) just switch to ServiceStack.Text library - it's like 30 seconds to integrate and you'll solve bunch of other problems. Take a look at this question posted & answered by me:

[ASP.NET MVC Json DateTime Serialization conversion to UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973286/asp-net-mvc-json-datetime-serialization-conversion-to-utc)